# Unable to coerce &String to &str

Tags: string, rust

I'm trying to compile the following code, from the Rust book at the Rust official website.

```
fn takes_slice(slice: &str) {
    println!("Got: {}", slice);
}

fn main() {
    let s = "Hello".to_string();
    takes_slice(&s);
}
```

At compilation, it throws the following error

> /devl/rust/bc_09/src/main.rs:7:17: 7:19 error: mismatched types:
>   expected `&str`, found `&collections::string::String` (expected str,
>   found struct collections::string::String)
>
> /devl/rust/bc_09/src/main.rs:7     takes_slice(&s);
>                                                  ^~ error: aborting due to previous error Could not compile `hello_world`.

Here is the Rust version I'm running: rustc 1.0.0-nightly (44a287e6e 2015-01-08 17:03:40 -0800)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a really old version of the nightly in Rust terms! Old enough that the `&String` -> `&str` coercion isn't available. You just need to upgrade to a newer version.